# $B\in\Bbb R$ has the property that given $b∈B$ there exists $k>0$ such that if $0<|b−x|<k$ for some $x∈\Bbb R$, then $x\notin B$. $B$ countable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

A subset $B$ of $\mathbb R$ has the property that given $b ∈ B$ there exists $k > 0$ such that if $0 < |b − x| < k$ for some $x ∈ \mathbb R$, then $x \notin B$. Is $B$ countable?

I tried using the diagonal argument here to show that $B$ is uncountable but I can't seem to make much progress...

Answer (score 1):

The property implies that for every $b \in B$ there exists $k_b > 0$ such that $\langle b - k_b, b + k_b\rangle \cap B = \{b\}$.

Pick a rational number $q_b \in \left\langle b - \frac{k_b}2, b + \frac{k_b}2\right\rangle$ and consider the map $f : B \to \mathbb{Q}$ given by $f(b) = q_b$.

Take $b,c \in B$ such that $q_b = q_c$. Assume $k_c \le k_b$. We have $$|b - c| \le |b - q_b| + |q_b - q_c| + |q_c - c| < \frac{k_b}2 + \frac{k_c}2 \le k_b$$

so $c \in \langle b - k_b, b + k_b\rangle \cap B = \{b\}$ which implies $c = b$.

Therefore, $f$ is injective. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, we conclude that $B$ is at most countable.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis clearly implies that $B$ has no limit points. By Bolzano - Weirstarss Theorem $B$ can have only finitely many points in $(-n,n)$ for any $n$. so $B$ is at most countable.

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer? Why does B have no limit points?

Comment: Didnt you see the word "clearly"?  He said clearly so it doesnt have to be justified. And to make himself appear smarter than you.  Thats why pretentious mathemeticians use that vocabulary.

Comment: I dont see the reason either, @MathematicianP. I think Kavi is confusing your neighborhood of $b$ not containing some x with containing no $x$ at all.  I think Kavi is getting nothing but isolated points from that.

Comment: You have a deleted neighborhood and a point such that  $x\in N^*(b, k)$ where $b\in B$ but $x\not\in B$.  Thats all I read, so I dont know where Kavi is getting his.  I gave a counter example in my answer.  If you said there was no $x$ at all satisfying the condition then Id agree with Kavi that you have only isolated points.

Comment: I think the statement is being read wrongly by people criticizing my answer. The hypothesis says no point of $(b-k,b+k)-\{b\}$ is in $B$ and that is why $B$ has no limit points. Perhaps the problem is with English.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum with your interpretation of the question isn't the set of all irrational numbers an obvious counterexample? I would have voted down this question if that was the correct interpretation. Please withdraw your comment on the way I used çlearly'.

Comment: @Kavi, the phrasing is "for some $x\in\Bbb R$", not "for all".  You are assuming the exact opposite quantifier than what is explicitly used in the question. There is no problem with English, there is a problem with your interpretation.

And the fact youd down vote a question you think is "beneath you" proves the pretentiousness I was talking about.  I can both read mathematics without confusion AND read between your lines at the same time.  If you think the question itself is incorrect, by all means explain so. HELP the asker instead of judging him.

Comment: @MathematicianP Let $B$ be the set of all irrational numbers. Given $b \in B$ take $k=1$. Do you agree that there exists $x$ with $0<|b-x|<k$ and $x \notin B$? Every open interval contains rational numbers, right? The set of all irrationals number is not countable, right? Do you now conclude that the question is wrong or that you might be mis-reading the question?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand your question.

Take interval $(0,2)= B\subseteq \Bbb R$ and let $b=1\in B$. Take $k=4>0$.  Naturally, for an $x=4\in\Bbb R$, we have $0<|1-4|=3<4$ .  Clearly $4\not\in B$ and $B$ is uncountable.